# Make boxplots of columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, boxplot

I am a beginner in R, and have a question about making boxplots of columns in R. I just made a dataframe:

```
SUS <- data.frame(RD = c(4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1), TK = c(4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1),
                  WK = c(3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2), NW = c(2, 2, 4, 2, NA, NA, 5, 1, 4, 2),
                  BW = c(3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1), EK = c(2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2),
                  AN = c(3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2))


rownames(SUS) <- c('Pleasant to use', 'Unnecessary complex', 'Easy to use',
                   'Need help of a technical person', 'Different functions well integrated','Various function incohorent', 'Imagine that it is easy to learn',
                   'Difficult to use', 'Confident during use', 'Long duration untill I could work with it')
```

I tried a number of times, but I did not succeed in making boxplots for all rows. Someone who can help me out here?

Comment: Do you want a boxplot for each column or for each row? If you'd like a boxplot for each column, `boxplot(SUS)` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as well using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
SUS %>% 
  #create new column and save the row.names in it
  mutate(variable = row.names(.)) %>% 
  #convert your data from wide to long 
  tidyr::gather("var", "value", 1:7) %>%
  #plot it using ggplot2
  ggplot(., aes(x =  variable, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=35,hjust=1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @blondeclover says in the comment, `boxplot()` should work fine for doing a boxplot of each column.

If what you want is a boxplot for each *row*, then actually your current rows need to be your columns.  If you need to do this, you can transpose the data frame before plotting:

```
SUS.new <- as.data.frame(t(SUS))
boxplot(SUS.new)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I indeed wanted to make a boxplot for each row. I was wondering if it is also possible to do this with ggplot?